# Can I get the locator string from a By?

Tags: c#, selenium

At the moment, I'm storing references to page elements as Bys:

```
public By showAllCheckbox = By.Id("show-all");
public By addArticleButton = By.CssSelector("a[id='add-article-btn']");
public By exampleEventCategoryEntityPickerPlusButton = By.XPath("//*[@id='j1_1']/i");
public By exampleEventReasonEntityPickerEntity = By.CssSelector("a[id='7603_anchor']");
```

Using selenium (or some other witchcraft) is it possible to get that selector string back out of the By? For example, for the add article button above I would want to get "a[id='add-article-btn']".

Thanks!

Comment: your issue get sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it as follows, You can use [toString()](https://selenium-by-arun.blogspot.com/2014/07/205-using-tostring-method-of-object.html)

```
By addArtclBtn = By.CssSelector("a[id='add-article-btn']");
String selector = addArtclBtn.toString();
```

selector value will be something like this `"By.cssSelector: a[id='add-article-btn']"`, Then what you can do is, just spliit the value by `": "`.

```
String[] splittedValues = selector.split(": ");
String value = splittedValues[1];
```

Comment: This is definitely the answer as it's beautifully simple. Thank you